# How do I get a point from two points using a right triangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry, triangles

In the image the triangle is made up of 3 points, 2 of which are found, the third one is missing, not sure how to get this last point. [Need an Equation]

[image: triangle missing a point]

Comment: It would just be $(5,4)$

Comment: how do you do that with an equation?, need an equation

Comment: Do you know the distance formula?

Comment: Thankfully i do, how do you use it to get (5,4)?

Comment: well if you call your unknown point $(x,y)$ then the distance from $(x,y)$ to $(4,4)$ is $1$ and to $(4,1)$ is $\sqrt{10}$ as per your diagram. This gives you two equations with unknowns $x$ and $y$ which you can solve easily.

Comment: .. i dont get it, even if i find the hypotenuse (sqrt(10)) what do i do to get x and y that's missing? ive been asking this over and over

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Distance from $(x,y)$ to $(4,4)$ is $|\sqrt{(x-4)^2+(y-4)^2}| = 1$

Distance from $(x,y)$ to $(4,1)$ is $|\sqrt{(x-4)^2+(y-1)^2}| = |\sqrt{10}|$

Square both sides of both these equations and subtract one from the other to get $(y-1)^2-(y-4)^2=10-1=9$. So you get, $$y^2+1-2y-(y^2+16-8y)=9\Longrightarrow 6y-15=9\Longrightarrow y=4$$
If you put $y=4$ an any one of the first two equations you will get $x=5$.